# I modified GTK3 source code and recompiled: No effect 

Tags: gnome, gtk, gcc

In Ubuntu (Gnome) there is absolutely no way the change the mouse wheel scroll rate for GTK applications. It is hard-coded in GTK and determined by a "smart" algorithm which dynamically depends on the window size.

So I downloaded the source and found the function that returns the step value. I changed it to return a very small number first, and then 0 (to see if it has any affect at all).

I did

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

as instructed by GTK website.

It compiles with no problems (I have the libraries)

Bu then, I restart and it has absolutely no affect. My guess is Ubuntu is still using the original GTK it shipped with. What do you think is wrong here?

Comment: please add to your question what exactly has been installed and where they have been installed i.e. from the makefile - names of libraries and path where they have been put.  The ubuntu version you are using would be useful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using the debian/ubuntu way of building from source as this ensures that all files goes to the intended directories. Running './configure' without any options usually sets PREFIX to '/usr/local'. Thus all the previous gtk files are still in place as they most likely reside in '/usr' and therefor gets loaded instead of the new ones you have compiled.

Try `apt-get source <package>` then modify the source to your liking.

Then to build the package do `dpkg-build -rfakeroot -uc -b` to build a .deb.
Then install the .deb with dpkg -i .

This will replace the current install of the package rebuilt.

However the apt tools will try to replace this package at every system update. But it's a good way to try out changes.